# Poner marcadores en google maps obtenidos a través de una API

Tags: flutter

Buenas tardes sigo con mi andadura en el mundo de las aplicaciones y Flutter. Bien, ya cree un mapa en el cual cuando arranco la app, me solicita permiso para la ubicación y seguido me muestra mi ubicación actual, pero ahora tengo que mostrar marcadores extraidos por latitudes y longitudes a través de una API.

Paso a detallar el código:

```
class CurrentLocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentLocationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CurrentLocationScreenState createState() => _CurrentLocationScreenState();
}


class _CurrentLocationScreenState extends State<CurrentLocationScreen> {
  //Con esta parte de aquí traigo las ubicaciones con la API
  List<Album> data = <Album>[];

  Future<List<Album>> tomar_datos() async {
    var url = 'http://url/api?api_key=key_cur_prod_fnPqT5xQEi5Vcb9wKwbCf65c3BjVGyBB';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var registros = <Album>[];
    for(datos in datos){
      registros.add(Album.fromJson(datos));
    }
    return registros;
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tomar_datos().then((value){
      setState(() {
        data.addAll(value);
      });
    });
  }
  //Hasta aquí el código para obtener las localizaciones

  late GoogleMapController googleMapController;

  static const CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962), zoom: 14);

  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
          markers: markers,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
            googleMapController = controller;
            final position = await _determinePosition();
            if(position != null){
              googleMapController
                  .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 16)));
              markers.clear();
              markers.add(Marker(markerId: const MarkerId('currentLocation'),position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude)));

              //Aquí arriba es donde quiero mostrar los markers, cada uno por su ubicación, pero no se como continuar
              setState(() {});
            }
          },
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("Location permission denied");
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied');
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    return position;

  }
}
```

Realizando pruebas en otro documento con otro widget que no es el de Google, simplemente imprimiendo las latitudes y longitudes si lo consigo, pero no se como llevarlo aquí.

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)
                      )
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(data[index].latitud),
                        Text(data[index].longitud),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Alguna sugerencia por favor!

---

**Edición según respuesta:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){
      registros.add(Album.fromJson(datos[i]));
      //DEPENDIENDO DE LOS DATOS QUE TE RETORNE LA API PUEDES VALIDAR QUE
      //LAS COORDERNADAS NO SEAN NULAS
      //ahora lo que haces es unicamente agregar en los marcadores la nueva coordenada, en tal caso que sea una lista de coordenadas, podrías hacer un ciclo for dentro de este if.
      markers.clear();
      markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('currentLocation'),
          position: LatLng(datos[i]['latitud'], datos[i]['longitud'])));
      
    }
```

Me obliga a poner un `MarkerId`, pero haciendolo así no me muestra nada, hay forma de comprobar que no viene vacio o algo así como un `console.log`??

Comment: Las coordenadas las obtienes por medio de la función obtenerDatos?

Comment: Hola @JonathanPerez las obtengo por `tomar_datos` si no me confundo

Comment: He cambiado el código un poco @JonathanPerez lo he puesto al final de mi pregunta, pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creería que podrías hacer un ciclo `for` clásico para poder validar cada index:

```
 Future<List<Album>> tomar_datos() async {
var url = 'http://url/api?api_key=key_cur_prod_fnPqT5xQEi5Vcb9wKwbCf65c3BjVGyBB';
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
var registros = <Album>[];
for(var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){
  registros.add(Album.fromJson(datos[i]));

  //DEPENDIENDO DE LOS DATOS QUE TE RETORNE LA API PUEDES VALIDAR QUE 
  //LAS COORDERNADAS NO SEAN NULAS
  if(datos[i]['latitud'] != null && datos[i]['longitud] != null){

    //ahora lo que haces es unicamente agregar en los marcadores la nueva coordenada, en tal caso que sea una lista de coordenadas, podrías hacer un ciclo for dentro de este if.
    markers.add(Marker(
      onDrag: null,
      onDragStart: null,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: datos[i]['nombre']),
      icon: //icono de tu marcador,
      position: const LatLng(datos[i]['latitud'], datos[i]['longitud']),
    ));
 }
}
return registros;
```

}

Espero y mi respuesta te haya servido

Para solucionar el tema de `Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'` tienes que parsear las coordenadas:

```
LatLng(double.parse(datos[i]['latitud'].toString()), double.parse(datos[i]['longitud'].toString()))
```

Comment: Hola @JonathanPerez me da error en distintos sitios, `_CurrentLocationScreenState` , `tomar_datos()`, `markers`,  `position`, `return registros`

Comment: Que datos te retorna la api?

Comment: No se como responderte a eso, me trae la latitud  y longitud además de una dirección @JonathanPerez

Comment: No me deja unime al chat, por el motivo que sea

Comment: Cuando arranca la aplicación me dice `Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

Comment: Los problemas que dijiste que te salían en el primer comentario, te siguen saliendo?

Comment: No, están solventados todos

Comment: ahorita edite mi respuesta para resolver el tema del type double, o en donde te salta ese error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137241/discussion-between-miguel-and-jonathan-perez).